# Unable to connect to Azure Windows 10 VM after PC reset

Tags: azure, rdp, windows-10, reset

After going:

> Start -> Setting -> Update & Security -> Recovery -> Get started -> Keep my files ...

In Windows 10 on the Azure VM. I am unable to connect to the vm with rdp - that was previously connectable getting the following message:

[image]

Did the factory reset deleted neccesary azure configuration files on the VM or what happened?

---

Same thing when: `Windows Security -> (Fresh Start) Get started` in Windows 10 - Leaves the vm unconnectable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly you will have lost configuration, which is causing your issue. Not too much you can do at this point. If you have data you need, you can deploy a new machine and mount the disks to the new VM to recover the data.

In future I suggest either taking a snapshot of the disk once the VM is running at a baseline, that way you can always re deploy back to that point, more information here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/snapshot-copy-managed-disk

Or use Azure VM Backup to take regular backups and then you can always roll back to the previous backup in case of issues, more information here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-first-look-arm

Comment: Yes. I am currently setting up a new vm and I am enabling the backup with `Recovery Services vault` this time.